# Why do I see confirmation box twice when I write Javascript only once in my document

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("a.sure").click(function () {
   var choice = confirm("Are you Sure");
});
```

I see confirm twice when I write this and click. When I track from Firebug then the confirm dialogue box only appears once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Triggers only once for me](http://jsbin.com/ihufi4).

**Sample HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="sure">Sure?</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a.sure").click(function () {
    var choice = confirm("Are you Sure");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

are you sure you have one only link with .sure class? (it seems a words-trick). Can you provide your markup code? have you tried with

```
$("a.sure").click(function () {
    return confirm("Are you Sure");
});
```